# Datepicker CalendarOpened when

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datepicker

I am using a `DatePicker` for WPF and .NET 4.5. I need to open a file when the user clicks the calendar and the drop-down opens. Should I signal an event handler? i.e.

```
    <Grid x:Name="Calendar_Loaded">
        <DatePicker Name="MyCal"  Margin="204,106,0,108" DisplayDateEnd="2015-12-31"  
                    DisplayDateStart="2015-01-01" Width="148" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Text="" 
                    BorderThickness="1.5" Background="#FF472020" Foreground="#FF242923" 
                    DisplayDate="2015-04-25" CalendarOpened="MyCal_File_Open" 
                    SelectedDateChanged="MyCal_SelectedDateChanged"/>
    </Grid>
```

So my question is, is this correct to setup the event handler on the `DatePicker` control?

The code behind is the following:

```
    private void MyCal_File_Open(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt", FileMode.Create))
        {
            fileStream.Write();
        }
    }

    private void MyCal_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Yes, `DatePicker.CalendarOpened`is a useful event. And No, the code you posted does not seem to self-explain what you want to do and what the problem is - it would not have compiled until it was edited, and would not work since C:\ root is write-protected in Windows by default, and since it apparently tries to create the same empty file allover again. Can you perhaps edit the question, maybe explain what the purpose of that file would be?

Comment: yes, I am trying to open a file to write the date selected to it and process the date. I then want to close the file after datepicker closes. Hence the MyCal_SelectedDateChanged event handler. Could I do it like that in three steps. ie 1.) Open file when DatePicker.CalendarOpened called. 2.) User selects a date and the DatePicker.SelectedDateChanged Event gets called. Then, I write the date to the file previously opened. 3.) And finally close the file upon the DatePicker.CalendarClosed event? I don't care that the file will get overwritten eventualy. Each time the user clicks a date it will be

Comment: Yes, what you described in your comment could be done that way. The pattern sounds unusual to me though - users directly typing in the control without using the calendar drop-down would escape you that way if that matters, and the purpose of the file you were talking about does not seem very obvious.

Comment: Should I make a persistent connection through data binding? To update a source from target? Like a button.click event on each calendar date selection. That way, I don't have to close and open file each time. It seems unusual. But, isn't that how opentable.com works? callback function? the target being a CalendarDayButton and the source being the filestream object?

Comment: If you'd have an MVVM "ViewModel", that one would have a public DateTime property, and the "View" would be {Binding ThatProperty}. That way the View would not need any code-behind, and the ViewModel would always know when the property is actually getting changed

Comment: I noticed that datepicker control has an internal textbox defined in the "PART_TextBox" Template Attribute. Should I bind to the text property that gets populated in that box after selection of date? So internally it's a DateTime?  Then, the data file i have open always changes as long as im selecting a date from the datepicker? But how do i set up the file.write(date). var date = MyCal.SelectedDate.ToString()

Comment: First: I am not clear about problem, 
When u hook up for calendar opened event you may open a calendar several times and u may endup in IO Exceptiosn may be... But I would recommend date changed or calendar closed events instead of opened..

Comment: @StefanWuebbe I think I figured it out. I have to connect the event handler using the += operator. By connecting I mean the "MyCal_SelectedDateChanged" event before I call it in the XAML. And the FileWrite operation I need to open a directory writeable by Visual Studio , ie "Documents\VisualStudio\Projects\". And I need to use UTFencode and set aside buffer for writing blocks of data at a time.And I have to use the fs FileStream object. I didn't mean fileStream.write directly. I know i have to create a handle.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it solved